# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'first-app' when create react app in subfolder of D

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, mkdir

I'm new with ReactJs, when I create-react-app in my D folder, it run successfully, but when I create react app in 'D:\workspace' it showed this screen:

```
node:fs:1398
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'first-app'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1398:3)
    at module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
    at createApp (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
    at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'first-app'
}
```

Node.js v18.18.0

I've checked File Explorer but there weren't any files named AppData, Local, and npm, I can go to it by cd command but when I used other command it said the file doesn't exist. Can anyone explain this to me, pls?

Answer (score 0):

Run command line with administrator rights will solve permission error.